# How i can impletement sms notifications in asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net

I want to know how we can add a sms notification functionality to a asp.net website.

I have searched a long time on google but i have not find a proper way to do it.

Please help me. How we can implement it ?

Thanks,
Rajbir

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [SMS Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway). There are many out there. Just Google for them and pick the one which meets your country coverage and of course budget requirements.